# Polarization of light and quantum spin states

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, polarization

In Sakurai's *Modern Quantum Mechanics* Chapter 1, he makes an analogy between polarized light and the results of the Stern-Gerlach experiment.

He compares the existence of a $S_{z}^{+}$ and $S_{z}^{-}$ component in an $S_{z}^{+}$ beam passed through an apparatus that splits the beam as $S_{x}^{+}$ and $S_{x}^{-}$ to polarized light that passes first through an $x$ filter followed by a filter at $45^{\circ}$ and then through a $y$ filter. In both cases, the beam appears to 'forget' what its initial state was, after it passes through the intermediary.

Now, Sakurai extends this analogy to write $S_{x}^{+}$ and $S_{x}^{-}$ as a linear combination of $S_{z}^{+}$ and $S_{z}^{-}$, thus exhausting all possible linear combinations using $S_{z}$ as a basis. He now asks how $S_{y}^{+}$ and $S_{y}^{-}$ should be written, now that $S_{z}$ has been exhausted. For this, he alludes to how circularly polarized light and linearly polarized light at $45^{\circ}$ both have equal components along $\hat{x}$ and $\hat{y}$, but are both represented in terms of the same basis; the circularly polarized light having complex coefficients.

My question is as follows. How can we compare the $y$ component of the spin state to *circularly polarized light*? Aren't circularly and linearly polarized light *different*? As in, circularly polarized light gives equal components along *any* set of perpendicular axes, however, a $45^{\circ}$ linearly polarized light doesn't for *any* set of axes: it has to be at $45^{\circ}$ to the perpendicular axes. On that note, $S_{x}$ and $S_{y}$ are identical, as in, they do not have this kind of difference, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we work in the circular basis for light: $|+\rangle$ and $|-\rangle$, then linear polarization is a linear combination:

$$ |\leftrightarrow\rangle = \frac {-i} {\sqrt 2}[|+\rangle - |-\rangle]$$

$$ |\updownarrow\rangle = \frac 1 {\sqrt 2}[|+\rangle +
 |-\rangle]$$

I used double arrows to indicate that it is a tensor polarization.

The orthogonal $\pm 45^{\circ}$ linear polarizations are then:

$$ \frac 1 {\sqrt{2}}[|\updownarrow\rangle \pm |\leftrightarrow\rangle ]$$

and they are equal combinations of $|+\rangle$ and $|-\rangle$ with different phases.

This is very similar to the spin 1/2 case, in which:

$$ |\uparrow\rangle_x = \frac 1 {\sqrt 2}[|\uparrow\rangle + |\downarrow\rangle]$$
$$ |\downarrow\rangle_x = \frac 1 {\sqrt 2}[|\uparrow\rangle - |\downarrow\rangle]$$

are the $x$-basis and

$$ |\uparrow\rangle_y = \frac 1 {\sqrt 2}[|\uparrow\rangle + i|\downarrow\rangle]$$
$$ |\downarrow\rangle_y = \frac 1 {\sqrt 2}[|\uparrow\rangle - i|\downarrow\rangle]$$

are the $y$-basis.

Linear polarized light is a tensor polarization, so a 180 degree rotation changes the state by $-1$, leaving it unchanged in the lab. A 90 degree rotation just flips the definition of horizontal and vertical, and a 45 degree rotation is an orthogonal diagonal basis. This is all because the photon is spin-1.

Spin 1/2 behaves differently. A 360 degree rotation changes the states by a phase factor of -1, while a 180 degree rotation flips the definition of up and down. (Note: "minus up is *not* down). A 90 degree rotation changes between orthogonal basis in $x$ and $y$.

You can continue this pattern to spin-2 gravitational waves. One may stretch vertically and squish horizontally and then half a cycle latter squish vertically and stretch horizontally. Thus, a 90 degree rotation adds a phase factor of -1, and 45 degree rotation gives the state that completes the orthogonal basis for the 2 states of polarization (see figure).
[image]